How to increase popularity of CSE?
When visiting Area 51 for Chinese Language I noted that our site has a relatively low number of questions per day asked at 3.9/day when 15/per day is considered healthy. What are some things that can be done to encourage more posting of questions? 

A quick review shows that a large number of users post answers but not questions (nothing wrong with this but just wondering how we might improve the stats). I began to think about the link to the stats on the questions page:

Which shows that just below the link to more site stats, an option for sharing the website on Social Media. I note that the options are primarily Western-based services and do not include the many social media outlets in Asia. 
Facts which give rise to the following additional questions:

Would it be possible to extend the sharing capability to other
widely used social sharing services?
Would it be useful to create a new badge for number of times the
    site has been shared with friends?
If the community decides that either of these features are useful,
how would they be implemented?


I think that what would help would be sharing not just the site with people you think might be interested, but also sharing particularly interesting questions. For example on Facebook or Twitter.
Stats are important but not that important. What is important is that we make sure the quality of the questions we get is good. The quantity will follow naturally. But if you focus on quantity, the quality will decrease and the quantity will also decrease because nobody is interested in a low-quality Q&A site. 

I think it is also a great idea to let college students learning Chinese know about the site, so the population here will grow largely.
